# Proprietary Docker Containers

Tags: docker

I'm looking for a way to distribute my applications in docker containers/stack.  These will go to clients who should be able to start and stop the containers; however, I would prefer they not reverse engineer the content within the containers or run containers on a host other than that which it is shipped on. What's the most effective method of distributing containers to customers?

So far as I can tell, securing the host and having the application follow traditional licensing methods is about as close as I'm going to get and that docker may not provide any added benefits.

Comment: Have you tried docker hub?

Comment: Docker hub is a public repository hosting your Dockerimages, you can go private if you want more control over where the Dockerimages are stored and who has access to those images, using a private registry: https://docs.docker.com/registry/

Comment: Yes, I've used Docker Hub and I use Sonatype Nexus on premise.  This is a concern of once the customer has a container, whats the best way of ensuring they are unable to reverse engineer the container and everything in it?